# Is a question about how to find a tutorial allowed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, subjective, tutorials

I want to ask a question related to finding good Windows 8 tutorials. For example, web sites I could go to for Windows 8 tricks. Would that be an appropriate question for Stack Overflow? Is that too subjective? How about for other Computer Science oriented stuff besides programming?

Comment: That question would not be on-topic anywhere on the network.

Comment: You're asking for people to refer you to external resources. This is a big no-no on Stack Overflow. People will vote to close your question on this basis.

Comment: On some sites, "How can I evaluate" some offsite resource like a book or a tutorial will be ok, while "please recommend" a list of offsite resources on that topic will not be. If you want to learn to use Windows 8, that's Super User more than Stack Overflow. Check http://meta.superuser.com/ to see if this version of the question is ok there.

Answer (score 5):

One of the existing close reasons is

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Tutorials fall under the off-site resources. So that would as a result make your proposed question off-topic.

Comment: Where would I go to ask about the login button not working on superuser?

Comment: @user3314801 Sounds like a question for [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/).

Comment: I know, but where do I go if I can't log into that. I can't log into Meta Super User either. That doesn't logically make sense. Is there another place I can try to get help on that site?

Comment: Can't log in to it @user3314801? You should be able to. You have an account, so that should work just fine.